# Costs of reactive programming with R2DBC

Tags: spring, reactive, r2dbc

world!

Is it correct to say that from one side reactive programming allows to use less threads (and less thread-switching) and process data partially by portions (by these threads),

but from other side memory consumption and GC load increases due to these Mono and Flux objects wrappers?